# CPU ID in VMware environment

Tags: vmware, virtual-machine

I have a software that creates an installation key when it is installed based on the CPU ID and Motherboard serial number. The software is installed on a VMware virtual machine and stopped working stating that the registration is for different hardware.

My question is can the program see my actual hardware it is running on, or does it only see VMware virtual hardware? And if the program only sees the VM "CPU ID" can that change?

Also, does the VMware hardware serial number actual have anything to do with physical hardware?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The information provided by VMware (or any other virtualizer) has absolutely no bearing on the machine it's run on. In fact you can move a VM from one physical host to another and the software inside the VM would have no clue that this had happened. That's largely the point of a VM.

The hardware serial number VMware generates (Which is just a GUID in fact) is just specific to that virtual machine, and that serial number is carried around when the VM is moved between hosts.

VMs are a pain in the ass to deal with in terms of hardware-based licencing. What you can do easily enough is detect that the software is running in a virtual environment and decline to execute.

Comment: Thanks for a quick answer!
The software I am working with I am told uses the CPU ID, and the software gave us an error that states it was registered for different hardware. What could have changed on the VM? IT is trying to blame the software and they are saying that nothing has changed on their physical server.
Thanks

Comment: When a VM is moved from one host to another, VMware gives you the option to change the virtual machine ID (or not) - I'd guess that someone clicked the 'yes' button.

Comment: If you're coming here in 2017, this answer is not correct (at least as of 2014 and beyond). VMware does indeed use the CPU ID, which can be masked to "fool" the VM into thinking it's on the original hardware. Search on *vmware cpu masking* for more details.